# Suppressing IRB warning when overriding irb_help alias

Tags: ruby, jruby, irb

I'm working on an application that's a glorified wrapper around irb, and I would like to override the "help" command (which by default seems to be an alias to irb_help).  I'm using the approach of executing the following code before allowing the user to do anything in the prompt:

```
class << self
    def help
        my_custom_help
    end
end
```

While this seems to work, I get an annoying warn message every time I start the application:

```
irb: warn: can't alias help from irb_help.
```

Is there any way to suppress this warning message?